# Issue Displaying Updated Webpage

Tags: caching, browser, upload, ftp

I am using Adobe Dreamweaver to Web Develop. I have uploaded the files via ftp to the web server, also went on the web sever to confirm the files are uploading. When going to view webpage in all browsers, the changes aren't there. What could possibly be wrong? I know it's not uploading the files the files are updating and uploading on the web server.

Comment: I just found out that when I navigate to the website and leave out "www" it works just fine. But if i include it updated changes are not shown.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution! The issue was the aName under the Domain settings. It works perfect now.